# wordpress cant install plugins/themes on fedora

Tags: wordpress, plugins, permissions, fedora, selinux

i can't install any plugins or themes on wordpress 4.3 by the panels on fedora 22.
i have checked:

1. selinux open
   chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/
2. the wp directories owner is apache.
3. the permissions are 744 on directories and 774 on uploads.

im out of ideas what to check, any help is welcomed.

Comment: Is it meant to connect to filesystem through direct, ftp, or ssh? What error are you getting?

Comment: when i install plugin it shows:                                                        Downloading install package from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/theme-check.20150818.1.zip…

Unpacking the package…

Could not create directory. i'm not sure but i think its ftp